# Publish-AzureServiceProject ignores the -configuration parameter?

Tags: powershell, azure

I'm trying to deploy an azure service. I already have the package (created it using cspack.exe).

I put in a folder only 2 files: `SomePackage.cspkg` and `SomeServiceConfiguration.cscfg`

when running from this folder the following command:

```
Publish-AzureServiceProject -Package .\SomePackage.cspkg -Configuration SomeServiceConfiguration.cscfg
```

i'm getting the following error:

```
Publish-AzureServiceProject : Path for service configuration doesn't exist in C:\Users\ronyl\Desktop\dep\ServiceConfiguration.Cloud.cscfg.
```

note that I gave the cmdlet a path to another configuration file. Why does it look for this specific configuration file?

I'm using version 2.3 of the azure SDK

Comment: did you try providing full path to the config file?

Comment: I think you need to try `New-AzureDeployment` command instead. Documentation for `Publish-AzureServiceProject` says it is for publishing _current_ project (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn495166.aspx). And `New-AzureDeployment` is to actually deploy (http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/jj152867.aspx). Names are somewhat deceiving.